# запуск bash-файлов, созданных в ОС Windows

Tags: linux, sh

Ситуация:
Создаю *.sh файл, содержащий несколько wget'ов (файл создается в винде), закачиваю его на внешний ресурс

В linux-терминале на другой машине (ubuntu) с помощью wget загружаю этот sh-файл и при попытке его выполнить получаю 404

Набираю те же wget'ы в другом sh-файле через редактор nano - все wget'ы проходят успешно

Только потом замечаю, что при запуске wget'ов из полученного снаружи файла wget'ы пишут ссылку с окончанием %0d

Куда копать, подскажите?

Comment: Делайте файл сразу в linux =)

Comment: А где вы создаете первый .sh файл ? Редакторы под window конец строки отмечают двумя символами 0D 0A. А под linux конец строки просто 0A. Так что да, файлы полученные с windows надо обработать, удалить 0D. (P.S. Не дай бог вам создать файл под MAC OS до версии 9, там конец строки один 0D)

Comment: dos2unix попробуйте, перевернёт все переносы строки как надо

Comment: @Mike создаю в простом блокноте, пробовал в FAR, Sublime

Comment: @kvvk и все они по умолчанию настроены на прописывание 0D 0A, вот вам и ответ на вопрос

Comment: @Dmitriy а нет такого редактора, чтобы в винде сразу для linux делать? сейчас много экспериментирую таким образом и хочется оперативнее всё это делать

Comment: @kvvk, у большинства «нормальных» редакторов есть выбор кодировки/окончания строк в диалоге/команде «сохранить как» или подобной...

Comment: Да хоть Notepad++, где можно установить кодировку конца строк. Я уж про всякие IDE не говорю

Comment: @kvvk в sublime есть опция VIew → Line Endings

Comment: @kvvk Есть , вот Вам посоветовали

Comment: @andreymal про Sublime можно оформить как ответ

Comment: @kvvk И ответ не будет относиться к вопросу никак и его никто никогда не найдет и не воспользуется. потому что вопрос про wget, который вообще никакого отношения к делу не имеет. на его месте может быть любая программа с параметрами

Comment: @Mike вопрос изменил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как указали в комментариях, всё дело в разнице конца строки в Windows и Linux: 0D 0A и 0D соответственно

Редактирование текущего файла через редактор sublime с установленным View->LineEndings->Linux и пересохранение ничего не дало.

Помог dos2unix. На удаленной машине скачанный *.sh файл преобразуется с помощью dos2unix.

```
wget "http://.../upd.sh"
dos2unix upd.sh
sh upd.sh
```

Comment: Чтобы исключить эту и подобные другие ошибки, передавайте параметры команде в кавычках. Ну, кроме самых тривиальных случаев типа `cat /proc/cmdline`.

Comment: Так короче: `wget -qO- http://.../upd.sh | dos2unix | sh`